# Highlighting math mode in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, syntax-highlighting

Is there anyway to highlight the content of mathmode in TeXShop? Right now only the `$` sign is in a different colour. I would want the text content inside the `$ $` to be highlighted.

[image]

Like, for example, `auctex` using emacs.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that syntax coloring can happen. That's especially true if you continue to use $...$ since the start and end of the math mode use the same character so missing a single $ can confuse the situation. Start using \(...\) for in-line maths and \[...\] for display math. However, since TeXShop isn't going to force you to do that and $...$ is still standard wwith Plain TeX I still thing it won't happen.

Comment: If we miss a single $ the code will not compile anyway. $ $ highlighting works perfectly well with many other editors too.

Comment: Just curious. What happens with those editors  if you have \$ or \verb"$" or and unmatched $ inside a verbatim environment?

Comment: It is exactly for that the colour matching helps. If there is an unmatched $ it will show the rest of the code as coloured.

Comment: But those unmatched $s were intensional. Why not make a key binding that gives `$#INS#$` when you press $? That way you don’t get unmatched $. The `#INS#` will be the position of the insertion point when expanded. Backspace and forward arrow will remove the first $ and skip over the second for those rare times you want an unmatched $ and \$ should work fine too.

Comment: $ $ works fine with other editors. you are assuming that there will be never any issues with typing the code which is not a correct assumption to made. for example emacs with auctex/ if you have \$ it shows the entire code in math mode thereby alerting you of an unmatched $. I just want to know if such a highlighting is possible in TeXShop.

Comment: But unmatched $ can be legal so the highlighting can be misleading and annoying.

Comment: How can unmatched $ be legal? Please explain. It will break the code.

Comment: I gave some examples above, \verb”$”, in a verbatim environment, \$ if not taken care of properly, in a comment.

Comment: I think you are just rambling on. The emacs editor works just fine with $ $, covering all the cases you have said, I was the said syntax highligting behaviour with TeXShop. Unless you have something to add towards that these comments are pointless.